# Why are there still posts in the first post queue?

Tags: support, first-post-review, first-answers, first-questions

Since the [first post queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-posts) has been split into [first questions queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-questions) and [first answers queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-answers), then why are there still nearly 800 posts in it (2021-08-30)?

[image]

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for the edit and the attached info!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current pending review tasks from "First post" were *not* migrated to "First questions" and "First answers" review queues, possibly due to some potential technical issues.

Quote from [the discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release#comment1231083_369016):

> TylerH: It would be nice if they took the effort to split out your progress on this queue so that you had it applied to the two new queues created from it, but I don't know if that amount of work is feasible.
>
> animuson: @TylerH It is not. It is calculated by counting the number of tasks you've completed in the queue, so granting progress would require **moving all the tasks between queues, which has the potential to break a lot of things** since the queues are similar but functionally different.
>
> <sup>(Emphasis added)</sup>

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that *new* first posts that *would* have gone into 'First posts' is now going into 'First questions' and 'First answers'. The number of items in 'First posts' has been steadily decreasing as the backlog is being cleared by people still doing reviews of 'First posts'.